# php isset($_GET['post_id']) issue

Tags: php, mysql

I don't what the problem in my code is.

I need `$sql` to be run first to get `$p_id`, but it run `$sql` in second place, so that I can't get `$p_id = (int) $_GET['post_id'];`.

Can you please tell me why?

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
include "db/db.php";    
$upload_path = "secure/content/blogpostimg";
if (isset($_GET['post_id']) && $_GET['post_id'] != '') {
$p_id = (int) $_GET['post_id'];
$sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blog_post WHERE post_id = '$p_id'");
} else {
$sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blog_post ORDER BY  post_id DESC");
}
while ($rel = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
$id = $rel['post_id'];
$sub = $rel['subject'];
$imgname = $rel['img_name'];
$img = $rel ['image'];
$msg = $rel['message'];
$date = $rel['date'];
$poster = $rel['poster'];
$cat_name = $rel['cat_name'];

echo "<h1>". "$sub" ."</h1>". "<br/>";  
echo '<img src="' . $upload_path . '/' . $imgname . '" width="200"  />  ';
include_once("func.php");
echo substr($msg, 0, 200)."..." . "<a href=index.php?post_id= '$p_id' 
target='_blank'>Read more</a>";
?>
```

Comment: Well, what does your URL/`$_GET` look like?

Comment: Can you show some url you are calling? And maybe you could use `if ((isset($_GET['post_id'])) && (!empty($_GET['post_id'])))`. My preferred way to look up a var set and not empty.

Comment: @Raubi That's redundant, `if (!empty($_GET['post_id']))` does the same thing.